# How to synchronise the Hibernate cache with external changes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Abc{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Abc")
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Cache
    private List<AbcAccess> accesses = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc_access")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class AbcAccess {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")

    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Abc abc;
}
```

Backgroud: Spring Boot + Spring JPA (hibernate) + Ehcache, 2nd level cache enable.

`Cache` is `org.hibernate.annotations.Cache`

configuration (written in kotlin):

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class AbcConifg{


    private val jcacheConfiguration: javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<Any, Any>

    init {
        val ehcache = jHipsterProperties.cache.ehcache

        jcacheConfiguration = Eh107Configuration.fromEhcacheCacheConfiguration(
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(
                Any::class.java, Any::class.java,
                ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(ehcache.maxEntries)
            )
                .withExpiry(ExpiryPolicyBuilder.timeToLiveExpiration(Duration.ofSeconds(ehcache.timeToLiveSeconds.toLong())))
                .build()
        )
    }

    @Bean
    fun hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(cacheManager: javax.cache.CacheManager) = HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {
        hibernateProperties -> hibernateProperties[ConfigSettings.CACHE_MANAGER] = cacheManager
    }
}
```

When I query `Abc` from the database, it will cache the result into 2nd level cache.

Now I insert one more `AbcAccess` into the database, then I query `Abc` from the database again, it will just get the result from the cache. And the `access` in `Abc` is not the real-time one, it misses one `access`.

Comment: Are these supposed to be JPA entities? What `@Cache` annotation is this? Hibernates? How does your cache configuration look like?

Comment: i have update the question @JensSchauder